# Is it possible to add mix-blend-mode to scrollbar thumb?

Tags: css

I have a scrollbar on my page, I want to add a mix-blend-mode on
my scrollbar thumb, unfortunately the logical way
of going by this doesn't seem to work, or am I missing something?

[heres a jsfiddle example of the problem](https://jsfiddle.net/cdky7qah/)

```
div {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 50px;
  }

  /* Track */
  ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background-color: red;
  }

  /* Handle */
  ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: white;
    mix-blend-mode: exclusion;
    border: 1px solid black;
  }

  /* Handle on hover */
  ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background: lime;
  }
```

As you can see,I have white on top of red which in theory should make the thumb cyan colored.

Comment: adding mix blend mode to `pseudo` element is **no way possible** ,you have to *make the scroll bar as a div* **,with some `js`**